# Not able to use unlink or unlinkSync with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, fs

So I am trying to save a file for when a user joins my website and delete it when they leave, I can create the file, But I am not able to delete it. I am using socket.io and filesystem (fs) to try this but I can't.

I've tried changing unlinkSync to just unlink but that does not work, It should have something to do with my computer but I can unlinkSync on my other projects, in the same location in a different folder on my desktop.

```js
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  connections.push(socket)
  if (!fs.existsSync('./userdatax')) {
  fs.mkdirSync('./userdatax');
}
  fs.mkdirSync('./userdatax/' + socket.id);
  console.log('connection made: %s sockets connected', connections.length)
  //disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
    console.log(socket.id + ' disconnected')
fs.unlink('./userdatax/' + socket.id, function (err) {if (err) throw err})
})
})
```

ERROR :

```
connection made: 1 sockets connected
disconncted made: 0 sockets connected
zUEZDSmfVdJnfwriAAAA disconnected
C:\Users\La Fam\desktop\project\server.js:40
if (err) throw err;
         ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\La Fam\desktop\project\u
serdatax\zUEZDSmfVdJnfwriAAAA'
```

Comment: you should use rmdir to remove directories, in docs: *fs.unlink() will not work on a directory, empty or otherwise. To remove a directory, use fs.rmdir().* [*](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are creating a folder instead of a file using:

```
fs.mkdirSync('./userdatax/' + socket.id); // this will create a folder
```

Probably you intend to create a file using:

```
fs.writeFileSync('./userdatax/' + socket.id, ''); // will create a file with empty content
```

And then you will be able to remove it using `unlink` or `unlinkSync`;

Or if you intend to play with folders then use [`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) module.